# Creating Unit Tests for OrderSummary or other generated Objects

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have multiple methods that make queries to the OrderSummary.

I have tried to mock the call to the database using the Test.start() and Test.stop() to try to insert an OrderSummary, but that is not possible.
I also tried to use the Test.loadData() to load a OrderSummary CSV data from a static resource. It also gives me an error.

I also tried to create an OrderSummary Using the ConnectApi createOrderSummary(orderSummaryInput), but also gives me an error saying that the method cannot be used in the test context and I need to set the isTest(SeeAllData=True) annotation which is not what I am looking for.

The last thing that I tried is to create the entire tree of an order to see if it create an OrderSummary:

1. Account
2. Product2
3. PricebookEntry
4. Order
5. OrderItem

But after all the inserts I still don't have the OrderSummary in my test.

There must be a simple way to mock those kind of objects in Apex, but I cannot find an answer, I only find examples online using simple objects like Account and Contact. Does someone knows how can I mock a return of a method or a call to database that uses the OrderSummary?